# How do I authorize every API request coming from the client (native)?

Tags: android, api, oauth, google-api, token

I'm building a mobile-only application where I am using OAuth 2.0 for handling user logins via Google and Facebook. When a user tries to login using Google strategy, the client gets an Access Token & a Refresh Token from the Google API.

I am passing on these tokens to the Server (node.js) and using the Access Token to validate the request for the **first time** by calling : https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo & passing the Access Token.

I will be storing the Refresh token on the server side (in the database) and on client side (native Android) as well.

After a user has been authenticated, for **every subsequent request** from the native client to the server, I want to authorize the request.. Should I use the saved Refresh token on the native and send it to the server to validate it? Should the server validate this Refresh token against the DataBase entry OR via a webservice call to the Google API to validate?

Or is there any other way of Token Based Authentication?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: did you read: http://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html and http://www.bdtool.net/third/android-doc/web-docs/training/id-auth/authenticate.html ? it might help

Comment: I did read those links but I still am a little confused @pskink . I have a token on my local storage and I want to pass this token to the server on EVERY REQUEST. e.g. <a href='/vendor/offer'>        --> on click of this link I want to send along a token to authenticate access to the partiular URL. How can I do this?